# MongoDB mapReduce function isn't quite working as it should

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query

I'm running the following on my two collections, named "players" and "pharmacies".

I'd like to join them on their objectId's `_id` and `pharmacy` like `ObjectId("1287943s76a87flkl2")`.

The issue I'm having is that when I run the mapReduce functions, the first one outputs it's rows to the "joined" collection and the second one outputs it's rows to the "joined" collection as well.

All I want to see in the new "joined" collection is the data where it has found a join. Currently it is placing all the data in from both collections which I don't want - only want the rows that have complete data.

```
//Merge data so it outputs a complete row of data from the reduce function, no rows should appear if they don't have all the data

player_map = function() {
    emit(this.pharmacy, {"firstname" : this.first_name, "lastname" : this.last_name, "email" : this.email});
}

pharma_map = function() {
    emit(this._id, {"name" : this.name, "country" : this.country});
}


r = function(key, values) {
  var result = {
      "firstname" : "",
      "lastname" : "",
      "email" : "",
      "name" : "",
      "country" : ""
    };

    values.forEach(function(value) {
      if(value.firstname !== null) {result.firstname = value.firstname;}
      if(value.lastname !== null) {result.lastname = value.lastname;}
      if(value.email !== null) {result.email = value.email;}
      if(value.name !== null) {result.name = value.name;}
        if(value.country !== null) {result.country = value.country;}
    });

    return result;
}

res = db.players.mapReduce(player_map, r, {out: {reduce : 'joined'}});
res = db.pharmacies.mapReduce(pharma_map, r, {out: {reduce : 'joined'}});
```

Players document

```
{
  __v: 3,
  _id: ObjectId("552496ea6215d31100fa1d984"),
  activation_code: 5633,
  country: "AU",
  createdAt: ISODate("2015-04-08T02:48:10.491Z"),
  email: "me@example.com",
  first_name: "John",
  password: "57467845742675427",
  pharmacy: ObjectId("5521d924847351c8243256")
}
```

Pharmacies document

```
{
  name: "Test Pharmacy",
  _id: ObjectId("5521d924847351c8243256"),
  products: [],
  country: "AU",
  createdAt: ISODate("2015-04-06T00:53:56.166Z"),
  __v: 0
}
```

I also tried this, and although it's inserting the country and name fields in the new merged collection, it's not inserting the data for the 2 fields.

```
db.players.find().forEach(function(pl) {
     pharmacies=db.pharmacies.find({_id:pl.pharmacy});
     pl.pharmacy_name=pharmacies.name;
     pl.pharmacy_country=pharmacies.country;
     db.merged.insert(pl);
});
```

Comment: This is normal, if you want to output only the data where a join exists then add a finalize function in your second mapreduce  job, where you can check if both parts of join exist and output results.

Comment: @nickmilon Yup I've just been reading the documentation on `finalize()` although I can't seem to get it. Any chance you could provide an answer with an amended version of the above? Struggling :/

Comment: Sorry I think I got it wrong, finalize can only transform documents from the reduced collection, while you intent to exclude documents, if this is your intention why don't you do a .remove({field_name :{$exists : false}}) on the reduced collection ?

Comment: db.joined.remove({$and :[{field1:{$exists:false}},{field2:{$exists:false}}.....]})

Comment: @nickmilon that just removed all the documents from the collection, instead of removing only the ones that don't have all the fields :/ `Cannot use commands write mode, degrading to compatibility mode
WriteResult({ "nRemoved" : 6682 })`

Comment: can you post here sample documents with and without joins

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76316/discussion-between-dt-dtdg-and-nickmilon).